# How to programmatically copy/paste in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, copy, paste

Is there a way to programmatically copy/paste text in **windows phone 8**. I want to copy the contents **from** the clipboard when user clicks a button.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

if the control is a clipboard then

You cannot get clipboard text from a Windows Phone application, only set it. Calling the GetText method in a Windows Phone application will always cause a SecurityException to occur.

You can only set text to clipboard in windows phone and can not read it.

check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard%28VS.95%29.aspx) link

Comment: The better link is the one specific to the Phone: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ms597033(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use **SetText** method from [**Clipboard Class**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.clipboard%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). The text will be copied into the mobile clipboard. Since **GetText** method will cause an exception, you can instruct the user, to hold the edit area until the paste option will appear, then the user can paste it from that option.